# How To Sort Or Filter Data By Highlight In Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to find out the cell that has being highlighted. I follow a [tutorial for the strikethrough](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1556-excel-sort-filter-by-strikethrough.html) and it works perfectly, just looking for something similar to it. Look through the documentation for excel functions but did not found what I looking for.

I know that color can be filter by using the filter color function provided by excel, but when I'm using Power Query/ Get and Transform in Excel 2016, it won't detect the cells that has being highlighted.

```
Function HasStrike(Rng As Range) As Boolean
HasStrike = Rng.Font.Strikethrough             #(change to find highlight)
End Function
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Range.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone` ?

Comment: `Rng.Interior.Color = #XXXXX` enter the colour in hex

Comment: Is there a way to detect the cells has being highlighted without specifying the color being highlighted? As I had multiple workbook, I need to combine and edit them using Power Query, and the color used to highlight cells are not consistent.

Comment: `Rng.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone` will get all the cells that have some colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
Function HasColour(Rng As Range) As Boolean
HasColour = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

However, I recommend using making a general HasParameter instead of one function for each one

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by making a general HasParameter?

Comment: I meant something like Chip Pearson's getInfo ( http://www.cpearson.com/excel/GetInfo.htm ), it's very useful and it does exactly what you want - you just pass it `getinfo(rng, "Interior.ColorIndex")`, or `getInfo(rng,"Font.Strikethrough")`, which is much better than making an individual function to test for each property you want to test